# Copy a file from desktop to server

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, web-services

I am dealing with this problem. I need to attach files from my desktop and store a copy of it in server and the url of the file location should be stored in a database. Can this be done using C#? please suggest me how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked Jan Jongboom's answer.

Here is another alternative using file access instead of a WCF service:

1. Get the path to the image file, using either System.Win32.OpenFileDialog for a dialog box, or DataObject for drag-and-drop.
2. Combine a fixed server UNC path (such as `\\MyServer\Share\Directory`) with the image file name using `Path.Combine()`
3. Call `File.Copy()` to copy the image to the server path you built in step 2
4. Store the server path in the database

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have a (WCF/ASMX) webservice on the server where the files should be stored; in the form of `void StoreFile(byte[]  file) { /* store this file and save in db */ }`.

Then you will have to add a 'service reference' to this webservice in your WPF application, and call it with `Service.StoreFile(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\path.exe"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan. So the StoreFile method will take the file and store it in database and all i need to do is to call the method and pass the name of the file right? But i am new to Wpf here, can you tell me how i can store in StoreFile method??

Comment: You will have to have two projects: 1. WCF Service, that runs on the server; and 2. WPF Application, that runs on the client. Check for 1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFWebService.aspx, and for 2. Right click on the 'References' folder in your WPF project. Then add a 'Service Reference' to your newly created WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has valid credentials on the server the `\\Server\share\filename` syntax can be directly used in c#.  If credentials need to be established you can shell out to `net use` or use the [WNetAddConnection2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385413%28VS.85%29.aspx) api

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Manipulating-Files-Directories.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link naveen but i am using C# and WPF for this.. also i wanted to copy the image file and not the word file..